# How to use Invoke-SQLcmd to insert a line AND get the ID of the line?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm using PowerShell and need to insert a line in an SQL Server table.
I need to get the ID of the inserted line.

```
$SQLQuery = "INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES('{0}','{1}',{2},{3},{4}}" -f $Variable01, $Variable02, $Variable03, $Variable04

$idflowinstance = Invoke-SQLcmd -ServerInstance $env:dataserver -query $SQLQuery -Username $env:user -Password $env:pass -Database $env:database
```

Comment: That does not look like a valid query - are you sure about the last `}`?

Comment: read it ')' instead of '}'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a `SELECT` statement after the `INSERT` to return the generated `IDENTITY` value:

```
$SQLQuery = "INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES('{0}','{1}',{2},{3},{4}};SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();" -f $Variable01, $Variable02, $Variable03, $Variable04
```

The scalar value from the DataRow result can be retrieved with this PowerShell expression after Invoke-SQLCmd:

```
$idflowinstance[0]
```